# Facing issues while creating value constructor for dynamic array in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing following code.

```
BiArray::BiArray(int arr[], int size)  {
    // IMPLEMENT ME
    arrsize_ = size;
    if (arrsize_*LO_THRESHOLD > INITIALCAP)
    {
    capacity_= arrsize_*LO_THRESHOLD;
    } else {
    capacity_= INITIALCAP;
    }
    position_ = ((capacity_ - arrsize_)/2 )-1;
    intrnlArr_ = new int[capacity_];
    for (int i=1; i < arrsize_; i++)
    {
    int a = i-1;
    intrnlArr_[i+position_]= arr[a];
    } 
}
```

It compiles but when I run a test in the following code I get a segmentation fault.

[image]

```
void BiArrayTester::testValueCtor() {
    funcname_ = "BiArrayTester::testValueCtor";

    int arr1[1] = {0};
    BiArray a1(arr1,1);
    if (a1.getSize() != 1 || a1.getCapacity() != INITIALCAP)
        errorOut_("size-1 value constructor incorrect size or capacity",1);
    if (a1[0] != 0) errorOut_("size-1 value constructor incorrect content",2);

    int arr2[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    BiArray a2(arr2,10);
    if (a2.getSize() != 10 || a2.getCapacity() != 30)
        errorOut_("value constructor incorrect size or capacity",3);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        if (a2[i] != i) errorOut_("value constructor incorrect content",4);

    passOut_("Tested the value constructor.");
}
```

Please help me to figure out my fault.

Comment: What is the intent? I am unable to determine what the constructor is supposed to do from the code.

Comment: the constructor is supposed to create an object similar to the other object.

Comment: You need to define similar. This is programming. It doesn't deal well with the fuzzy and hand wavy. What exactly do you want to to happen?

Comment: _Value constructor. Sets capacity of internal array to either. LO_THRESHOLD*size, or INITIALCAP, whichever is bigger,and initialize contents of BiArray to be same as the input array arr. Contents should be centered.For example, if arr = [1,2], then using the notation in the pdf, the internal array should be like [X X 1 2 X X] size is the size of arr. If size is not actually the size of arr, behaviour is undefined_


**Constructor should do the above things**

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation fault is caused by this line `intrnlArr_[i+position_]= arr[a];`. `i+position` gets greater than `capacity_-1`, which is the greatest available index in the array.

Comment: I think not , because  `position = ((capacity_ - arrsize_)/2)-1 `

Comment: What are the values of LO_THRESHOLD and INITIALCAP. I have deducted that if arrsize_ >= capacity + 4, you will go beyond the greatest available index and cause the segmentation fault.